I am creating the backend of youtube, facing issues while uploading pictures to cloudinary
I am trying to get input from the user and storing username, email, password, fullname in mongoDB and uploading avatar and cover image file to cloudinary everything else is working fine I am able to upload avatar file to cloudinary and getting the file path in mongodb document as well but cover Image file is not getting uploaded to cloudinary it is returning an empty file path which looks like this: "". I tried to log "coverImageLocalPath" as well it is showing "undefined" I have created "uploadOnCloudinary" function as well.
Github Repo Link: https://github.com/Sarab71/youtube-backend
Note- avatar is being uploaded but coverImage is not getting uploaded
path of this code: src/controllers/user.controller.js
import { asyncHandler } from "../utils/asyncHandler.js";
import { ApiError } from "../utils/ApiError.js";
import { User } from "../models/user.model.js";
import { uploadOnCloudinary } from "../utils/cloudinary.js";
import { ApiResponse } from "../utils/ApiResponse.js";

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { fullName, email, username, password } = req.body;

  if (
    [fullName, email, username, password].some(
      (field) => !field || field.trim() === ""
    )
  ) {
    throw new ApiError(400, "All fields are required");
  }

  const existedUser = await User.findOne({
    $or: [{ username }, { email }],
  });
  if (existedUser) {
    throw new ApiError(409, "Username or Email already exists");
  }

  const avatarLocalPath =
    req.files &&
    req.files.avatar &&
    req.files.avatar[0] &&
    req.files.avatar[0].path;

  const coverImageLocalPath =
    req.files &&
    req.files.coverImage &&
    req.files.coverImage[0] &&
    req.files.coverImage[0].path;

    console.log(coverImageLocalPath );
    
  if (!avatarLocalPath) {
    throw new ApiError(400, "Avatar is required");
  }

  const avatar = await uploadOnCloudinary(avatarLocalPath);
  const coverImage = await uploadOnCloudinary(coverImageLocalPath);
  if (!avatar) {
    throw new ApiError(400, "Error uploading avatar");
  }

  const userData = {
    fullName,
    avatar: avatar.url,
    coverImage: coverImage?.url || "",
    email,
    password,
    username: username.toLowerCase(),
  };

  const user = await User.create(userData);

  if (!user) {
    throw new ApiError(500, "Error while registering user");
  }

  const createdUser = await User.findById(user._id).select(
    "-password -refreshToken"
  );

  if (!createdUser) {
    throw new ApiError(500, "Error while fetching user data");
  }

  return res
    .status(201)
    .json(new ApiResponse(200, createdUser, "User registered successfully"));
});

export { registerUser };


Seems from your code that req.files.coverImage wasn't set - are you sending a file from the frontend? Is there middleware like multer in place for handling the file attachments?
